# SQL Server 2014 log growing just in Navision 2015 just when always on is active

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, availability-groups

My question is about if anybody can help me to find out why my LOG file growing to more than 2T just when I activate `ALWAYS ON` in my NAVISION database. 
I have more databases in my SQL Server 2016 and I have configured for my CRM DB and others and there is no problem. But with NAVISION I have problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

- Full recovery model and no log backups?
- AlwaysOn not pushing data? (so unable to re-use the log filespace)